# Conditional expectation defined on partition of the sample space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be a measure space.
>   Let $\{A_1,A_2,\dots\}$ be a partition of the sample space $\Omega$, where $A_i \in \mathscr{F}$ and $\bigcup_i A_i=\Omega$ with $P(A_i)>0$. Let $X$ be an integrable random variable. Show that
>
> $\displaystyle{E[X|\sigma\{A_i,i\geq1\}]=\sum_i \frac{E[X \chi_{A_i}]}{P(A_i)}\chi_{A_i}}$
>
> where $\chi$ is the characteristic function.

Let $\displaystyle{Z=\sum_i \frac{E[X \chi_{A_i}]}{P(A_i)}\chi_{A_i}}$. Then I want to prove for every $A \in \sigma\{A_i,i\geq 1\}$

$\int_A X dP = \int_A Z dP$.

and $Z$ is  $\sigma\{A_i,i\geq 1\}-$measurable.

$Z$ is obviously measurable w.r.t. $\sigma\{A_i,i\geq 1\}$. But how to prove $\int_A X dP = \int_A Z dP$?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think it goes something like "let $\mathscr{G} = \{A \in \mathscr{F} : \int_A X \mathop{dP} = \int_A Z \mathop{dP}\}$ and show it is a $\sigma$-algebra. Then $\sigma\{A_i, i \ge 1\} \subseteq \mathscr{G}$." The hard part is showing it is a $\sigma$-algebra; you might need some extension theorem for that.

Comment: The problem is relatively easy if you are willing to appeal to the result that you only need to establish the orthogonality condition $\int_A XdP=\int_A ZdP$ for $A$ in a set that generates the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma\{A_i,i\ge 1\}$. Ie, $A=A_i$ for some $i$.

Comment: @snarfblaat Thanks. I now know how to do it.